stateless vs stateful queries
I am working in supabase postgres and wrote multiple postgres functions
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS setup_auth_user;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setup_auth_user(
    email_value TEXT,
    name_value TEXT,     
    password_value TEXT,
    wallet_address_value TEXT,
    private_key_value TEXT
) RETURNS user_info AS $$
DECLARE
    updated_user_info user_info;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_info (user_state, email, name, password, updated_at)
    VALUES ('active'::user_state, email_value, name_value, password_value, now())
    RETURNING * INTO updated_user_info;

    insert into user_wallet_info (private_key, wallet_address, user_id)
    VALUES (private_key_value, wallet_address_value, updated_user_info.id);

    RETURN updated_user_info;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

and say this
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.get_user_with_authenticator;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_user_with_authenticator(session_id_value text)
 RETURNS jsonb
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
        'email', u.email,
        'name', u.name,
        'id', u.id,
        'user_state', u.user_state,
        'credential_id', pa.credential_id,
        'credential_public_key', pa.credential_public_key,
        'counter', pa.counter,
        'transports', pa.transports,
        'challenge', p.passkey_challenge
    )
    FROM passkey_sessions AS p 
    LEFT JOIN user_info AS u ON u.email = p.email
    LEFT JOIN passkey_authenticator AS pa ON pa.id = u.authenticator_id
    WHERE p.session_id = session_id_value;
$function$;

I call insert function on backend and setup_auth_user and get_user_with_authenticator on frontend
For this I have received this feedback

Seems easier to debug with stateless queries than when you have to create/update the function every time you edit it. You also don't need a migration to change a query.

Can someone please explain me what does it mean to have stateless queries? and also if it is a good idea?

Who did provide this feedback and what do they mean by "stateless"? I guess you should rather ask them for explanation, not StackOverflow.

That sounds like a question for the author of that feedback but my understanding is that this distinction of queries between stateful and stateless, while not necessarily any official/widely used nomenclature, refers to the fact your function-wrapped query has to be defined and present on the db before you can call it with a select, which raw/unwrapped/direct/stateless query doesn't require.
The "stateless" query only has to be maintained in the app code, where it's issued from. If you use a function wrapper, you need to maintain the code that calls it with a select in the app, and also the definition in the db, and to change the db you need a migration. When you change something about it, you need to update code in two places, one of which might be complicated/intrusive if there's a lot of before/after steps (backups, validation, integrity checks, tests) configured to be triggered by a migration. If you use a query directly, you just change the query.
There are some advantages to function-wrapping, if you came here for ammo to fire back at that feedback:

The query logic is abstracted away, leaving just a call, ideally with a descriptive, expressive name.
The function can be re-used in multiple places, similar to prepared statements or query strings with placeholders (if you like SQL injections). You don't need to copy the same big query in multiple places if that's the alternative.
Whenever something changes about the objects targeted by the query, or the query itself gets optimised, refactored, corrected by a linter, you leave all your function calls untouched.
You're reducing the mixing of SQL syntax into your app language. You can read and process SQL in tools designed or configured to understand it, without trying to detect or catch it appearing in a string in some other language. This works together with 1 and 2.
Your migrations are plain SQL scripts and you might have tools that process those also. By placing your queries together with the rest of your SQL code base, you can process all that in one go. It might also be easier to maintain the query right where all objects it's referencing are defined and catch that a change to a table needs to be cascaded to the function wrapping a widely used query that targets it.


To me it sounds that the providers of the feedback consider "stateful" to mean "something that is stored in a database", so a database function is stateful, but code that is stored (!) as part of the application is stateless.
That is pretty silly.
But what they are really saying is: we feel more comfortable debugging code in our application than debugging code in the database. That is a valid consideration.
My personal opinion is that you should keep code on the client side unless

it needs to be in the database to ascertain data integrity (triggers)

you cannot get good performance otherwise (for example, because the network latency is too high)


